# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'- How to write my query - VB.net and Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am using this two table one is 
User & EmployerUser

My application programming language is asp.net and vb.net

i am using this query

`Select name, email, password FROM user WHERE id =(Select userid FROM employeruser WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid= 96)`

but its giving a error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user

i have tried changing user into User. but both showing the same result

Even if try the simple query like

```
Select name, email, password FROM user WHERE id=2824
```

its also saying same error.

my table name is user. and i can't change this table name or any column name of any table now. it will cause a huge problem.

can anyone tell me what is i am doing wrong.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of time and effort if you avoid using [SQL Server Reserved Words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for table or column names. (Here, `User`)

Comment: Thank you for the information. this is a very old database which is used by our company. and developed by our old developer. we can't change anything now. it will cause a awful lot of work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
     SELECT NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD FROM [USER] 
     WHERE ID =(SELECT USERID FROM EMPLOYERUSER WHERE EMPUSERTYPE=1 AND EMPLOYERID= 96)
```

This is because you have used keyword USER

Comment: Thank you. You are an angel. I am trying this from yesterday.. and you solved in one minute